# jQuery, Insert Date Before Item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
  <li data-date="May 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="May 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="May 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="August 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="August 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
</ul>
```

What I want outputting is:

```
<ul>
  <li><h2>May 2014</h2></li>
  <li data-date="May 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="May 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="May 2014">Content</li>

  <li><h2>August 2014</h2></li>
  <li data-date="August 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="August 2014">Content</li>

  <li><h2>November 2014</h2></li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
  <li data-date="November 2014">Content</li>
</ul>
```

So, basically before every group of `li` elements which contain the same `data-date` value I want `<li><h2>{{ data-date group name }}</h2></li>` inserted.

I tried and failed using the following:

```
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).before('<li><h2>' + $(this).attr('data-date') + '</h2></li>');
});
```

This doesn't target *groups* of elements with the same `data-date` value, it targets every individual element.

So yeah, if anyone could help out on this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var previousDataDate;
$('li').each(function() {
    if (previousDataDate != $(this).attr('data-date')) {
        $(this).before('<li><h2>' + $(this).attr('data-date') + '</h2></li>');
    }
    previousDataDate = $(this).attr('data-date');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GPrS2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if you filtered it to get the first ocurrences:

```
var $firstDates = $('li').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).data("date") != $(this).prev().data("date");
});

$firstDates.each(function() {
  $(this).before('<li><h2>' + $(this).attr('data-date') + '</h2></li>');
});
```